# Digital Signature Service PAdES with PDF A-2

Tags: java, pdf, digital-signature, pdfa

Hi we are currently trying to sign a PDF A-2 compliant file with the Digital Signature Service library (DSS) based on this example(https://github.com/esig/dss/blob/master/dss-cookbook/src/test/java/eu/europa/esig/dss/cookbook/example/sign/SignPdfPadesBTest.java) which works basically fine. Also the signature validation afterwards is successful. The problem is that the result is no longer PDF A-2  compliant.
Is there anything that makes it possible to keep the A-2 compliance maintained? I tried the same code with a PDF A-1 compliant file where everything works fine and the result is expected. May it be that the DSS is simply not supporting PDF A-2?

Comment: Maybe you should ask the author(s) of that code? They might well ask you what's telling you that signing it is making it non-compliant

Comment: I wanted to do that. But it proves rather difficult to contact the authors. The jira is not accessible. It is not possible to create issues in github and so on.

Comment: *"The jira is not accessible."* - You merely need an account which is easy to get. And there actually is a recent entry that might help you, see https://ec.europa.eu/digital-building-blocks/tracker/browse/DSS-2981